# Time to send a query to Sql Server in asp.net MVC

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-4

Let's say I have a simple ASP.NET MVC web application and a (local) Sql Server. As an ORM, I am using Entity Framework 4.3.1

To figure out how long it takes on the ORM side, I've prepared a simple select query and printed out timestamps, like

```
 ...
 using (var context = Entities()) 
 {
     (1) timestamp1
     var list = context.Database.SqlQuery<Entity>("select * from entities").ToList();
     (2) timestamp2
 }
 ...
```

At the same time, I watched Sql Server Profiler to see the query start/end times.

The result is as follows (note that only milliseconds are shown since the query-processing time is less than 1sec)

1. timestamp1:       149 msec
2. query start time: 197 msec
3. query end time:   198 msec
4. timestamp2:       199 msec

Question) why so much time (48 msec, 197-149 msec) was taken before starting the query? is there any way to reduce this?

thanks!

Comment: You don't think that establishing a connection to the database, validating permissions etc. can be instantaneous, do you?

Comment: a similar performance was measured even though the connection is established before timestamp1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADO.NET EF needs to initialize itself, you'll find that future queries will execute without as much lag. Also don't forget that SQL Server Profiler only logs execution time for the query, not time associated with network transport and other overheads.

There might also be slowdowns associated with activating SQL Server - you say it's local on your computer, so it's possible that SQL Server's components were paged-out to disk. What is performance like when you run against a dedicated SQL Server box?